# I need to make an application-test.properties path 100% unique at startup for a spring boot unit test

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I need to make an application-test.properties path 100% unique at startup for a spring boot unit test.

I was thinking I could use the current time in milliseconds, or a generated UUID, but I don't know how I would do that from within a properties file.

I'm using some of the jenkins variables plus some defaults for local testing to get it closer, but it's not 100% certain due to the way the pipeline was set up.

#### Current application-test.properties:

```
data.path=tmp/Bob/test-${BRANCH_NAME:local}-${BUILD_ID:local}/source
```

#### I'm looking for something like this:

```
data.path=tmp/Bob/test-${BRANCH_NAME:local}-${BUILD_ID:local}-${UUID.randomUUID().toString())}/source
```

or

```
data.path=tmp/Bob/test-${BRANCH_NAME:local}-${BUILD_ID:local}-${System.currentTimeMillis()}/source
```

or
something similar.

Note: I can't mess with the pipeline at this time, or I'd just create a variable for this purpose.

Comment: This seems highly unusual.  What are you attempting to actually accomplish with this uniqueness?

Comment: Prevent the evil pre-existing camel flow from picking up and stealing the file that was meant for the good and kind JUnit's camel flow.

Comment: There are methods which exist that allow you to test Camel routes which rely on a specific path without *really* setting that path up on properties files, as I've come to experience that those kinds of tests get more and more brittle as we add in workarounds like the one in your question.

Comment: If you add an answer, I'd be happy to take a look.

Comment: It'd probably be better if you asked a domain specific question.  This is one which is specific to Spring Boot, but if I saw your tests and saw what you were trying to accomplish through Camel, I'd be able to actually answer in a more narrow context.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Spring boot provides a [random property source](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-external-config.html#boot-features-external-config-random-values). This lets you inject random ints, longs, and even UUIDs into your properties.

Comment: This was exactly what I was looking for.